# How to recognize variables like built-in functions?

Tags: functions, syntax-highlighting

Many built-in functions can recognize variables. For example, function 'Table' makes its iterator change color.
How can I implement a function that has a similar behavior? In this function, I can pass a symbolic expression to it and specify some target variables.

Comment: See the `SyntaxInformation` docs (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SyntaxInformation.html) and also questions about its use here. The `"LocalVariables"` property is what you need.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch That's exactly what I want to find. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the *built-in* `SyntaxInformation[]` as follows:

```
SyntaxInformation[f] = {"LocalVariables" -> {"Plot", {2, Infinity}}};

f[Sin[x] + 1, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to colorize variables using different template? I tried "LocalVariables" -> {{"Table", {2, 2}}, {"Solve", {3, 3}}} but it didn't work.